# Excel formula help required

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am a new user on Excel and looking for help. I have a table consisting of 3 columns..Start, End,and Area. I want to be able to input a start point and end point then in the area column I want it to display all the area between the 2. For example if I put 0.3 in the start column,1.5 in the end column I want the area column to display a all numbers inbetween ie 0.4,0.5 all the way to 1.5. I have Got an index start point from the "start" sorted just can't complete the list.

Hope someone can shed some light

Comment: There are infinite numbers between any two numbers.  Can you clarify?  It would help to give an example of what the result should look like.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) may prove useful reading

Comment: Better you share the method or mathematics you are using to get the Area, will help us to formulate the exercise using Excel Function !!

Comment: Start and End values is not enough. Step value needed.

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX()` is happy to provide a "reference" (in this case, "cell address" is the same thing. IF, and ONLY if, you make sure that Excel cannot make sense of what you enter if it were to provide values instead.

For example, if Excel can think you want 0.3 and 1.5 (values) returned, it WILL think that and WILL return those values. However, it your expression can only make sense to Excel if it has to return cell addresses instead, then it will do so. You cannot force it to provide a reference, only make it clear that values will not fit the formula, and then it will comply.

In your case, it is as simple as having two `INDEX()` functions with a colon between them. And then it will return the two references involved in the form of an active range. You don't have to use `INDIRECT()` on it as it is already active, so that's a nice bonus as well.

Do two `INDEX/MATCH` formulas, one for the start point and one for the end point. Each should return the `value or address` from Area column. The colon between them will make Excel choose the two addresses rather than the two values. You will then have a range as the output.

For example, the following formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:B5,MATCH(D1,A1:A5,0),2):INDEX(A1:B5,MATCH(D2,A1:A5,0),2)
```

The range will be displayed as the formula's output.

In 2021 when I write, `SPILL` functionality makes the range `SPILL` as needed. In 2019, one would have had to use `{CSE}` entry when finished with the formula (<kbd>CTRL-Shift-Enter</kbd>). You would want to include more rows in your `{CSE}` cell set but the extras will have an error in them. You can make a more complicated formula, with `INDIRECT()` wrapped around a string built of `ROW()` and the number of rows in the reference you built. I shall not add that as I am answering a couple years later, for people searching on the problem and hoping for a solution they can use post-2021. They can use `SPILL` which will obviate the need for `{CSE}` and its problems.

It is the basic use of how to get a reference (range in this case) from `INDEX()` when Excel would REALLLLY prefer to give you values instead.